# Controlling Google Geocharts with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I wanted to incorporate Google Geocharts on my site, so I included the code from their guidelines and it's all working smoothly.

However, I would like to add a couple of radio buttons to the site, which would control which region is being shown on the chart.

I understand that I need to change the variable region from below code from '150' to the value of the radio button when I click it, but I don't have much experience with Javascript, and would love some pointers how I can do that.

Thank you.

```
      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {
        region: '150',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the chart's `options` based on radio input is pretty straightforward

just need to find the region inputs and add a click handler

then get the value of the radio that was clicked

see following working snippet, which uses the first radio by default...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawRegionsMap,
  packages: ['geochart']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700],
    ['Tunisia', 220],
    ['Cameroon', 420]
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  var options = {};

  // init regions
  var regions = document.getElementsByName('region');
  var defaultRegion = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
    regions[i].addEventListener('click', drawChart, false);
    if (regions[i].checked) {
      defaultRegion = regions[i];
    }
  }
  if ((defaultRegion === null) && (regions.length > 0)) {
    defaultRegion = regions[0];
    defaultRegion.checked = true;
  }
  drawChart({target: defaultRegion});
  
  // radio on 'click' handler
  function drawChart(sender) {
    options.region = null;
    if (sender.target.value !== 'all') {
      options.region = sender.target.value;
    }
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div><input type="radio" name="region" id="all" value="all" /><label for="all">All</label></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="region" id="africa" value="002" /><label for="africa">Africa</label></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="region" id="americas" value="019" /><label for="americas">Americas</label></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="region" id="europe" value="150" /><label for="europe">Europe</label></div>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```